Joi add text/valid values to error message for custom validation function
I try to check in a joi schema (with a custom validation function) if a string is in a array.
The problem: the error message does not print what are the valid values was, compared to the build in .valid() method:
const Joi = require("joi");

const allowed = ["admin", "user", "noob"];

const method = (value, helpers) => {
  
    if (!allowed.includes(value)) {        
      return helpers.error("any.only", {allowed});
    }
  
    return value;

};


const createProfileSchema = Joi.object().keys({
    username: Joi.string().required().custom(method),
    text: Joi.string().valid("a", "b")
});
    

const { error, value } = createProfileSchema.validate({
    username: "asfd" ,
    text: "c"
}, {
    abortEarly: false
});
          

console.log(error || value);

[Error [ValidationError]: "username" must be one of . "text" must be one of [a, b]] {
  _original: { username: 'asfd', text: 'c' },
  details: [
    {
      message: '"username" must be one of ',
      path: [Array],
      type: 'any.only',
      context: [Object]
    },
    {
      message: '"text" must be one of [a, b]',
      path: [Array],
      type: 'any.only',
      context: [Object]
    }
  ]
}

How can i add like in .text error message the part [admin, user, noob], that the complete error message is "username" must be one of [admin, user, noob] and not just "username" must be one of 

I took a look into the source code: https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/5b96852fe07a742a8733f2bff1303d50853ca65c/lib/types/any.js#L169C46-L169C52
Joi expects a property called "valids".
      return helpers.error("any.only", {
        valids: allowed
      });

Fixed my problem.
[Error [ValidationError]: "username" must be one of [admin, user, noob]. "text" must be one of [a, b]] {
  _original: { username: 'asfd', text: 'c' },
  details: [
    {
      message: '"username" must be one of [admin, user, noob]',
      path: [Array],
      type: 'any.only',
      context: [Object]
    },
    {
      message: '"text" must be one of [a, b]',
      path: [Array],
      type: 'any.only',
      context: [Object]
    }
  ]
}

